# SQL Server - Hasbytes in function gives different result then in select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, salt

I created a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.HashCheeseName (@CheeseName NVARCHAR(40)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(40) 
AS BEGIN
 DECLARE @Salt VARCHAR(25)
 DECLARE @CheeseName NVARCHAR(40)
 DECLARE @output VARCHAR(40) 
 SET @Salt = '123abc11aa'

 SET @output = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(@CheeseName as VARCHAR(40)) + @Salt)
 RETURN @output
END
;
```

When I just run

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST('SwissCheese' as VARCHAR(40)) + @Salt)
```

I get an expected result like `0xF456D41144584064AC5456B7E3`...

However, when I run the function in a query

```
SELECT dbo.HashCheeseName('SwissCheese')
```

I get a result like this: `h:Mó!yýŠù’p» ªu_aøP¾æhw`

Any ideas on why it would result in something like this? At first sight it looks like a conversion issue, but I don't see the problem

Comment: ...but you said the function returns `VARCHAR(40)`. Of course SQL Server is going to convert it to that, then. (The actual type is `VARBINARY(8000)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing there isn't the same. `HASHBYTES` returns a `varbinary` ([Hashbytes (Transact-SQL) - Return Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-value)) where as your function is returning a `varchar`. Those are different datatypes. As a result, the last line of your function is effectively:

```
SET @output = CONVERT(varchar(40),HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(@CheeseName as VARCHAR(40)) + @Salt));
```

The `varchar` representation of a `varbinary` will not be the same. Either return a `varbinary` in your function, or your test `SELECT` with a `CONVERT` to a `varchar(40)`.

*Edit: To confirm, the solution is to simply change the return type of your function and variable:*

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.HashCheeseName (@CheeseName NVARCHAR(40)) 
RETURNS varbinary(8000)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Salt VARCHAR(25);
    DECLARE @CheeseName NVARCHAR(40);
    DECLARE @output varbinary(8000) ;
    SET @Salt = '123abc11aa';

    SET @output = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(@CheeseName as VARCHAR(40)) + @Salt);
    RETURN @output;
END
```